# garage door opener motor running constantly

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a B & D controll-a-door 4 (CAD-4) opener for a tilt garage door.  The model no. is 062200 and the unit was installed about 20 years ago.  About a week ago, the motor started running constantly, even when the door was not in use.  Needless to say, the opener does not function - just the motor running non-stop. I've had to disconnect the power supply because of the noise.

I've been told it might be a worn drive gear but when a repairman visited, he said the problem was the circuit board (although he didn't actually look at it).    He said replacing the circuit board was not an option because the (long) antenna is 28 MHz which is no longer made.  Only replacement boards with (short) 433 MHz antennas are available and they are not compatible with my unit.  He said due to its age, the whole unit would have to be replaced with a brand new opener.  Does this sound plausible?  I'm a keen re-cycler and would rather repair than replace so I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: this is a case where the cost of a new unit is far less than the cost of paying a pro to even look at it.

Comment: I’ll agree with @agentp, and add that anew unit will be more secure because there have been a lot of improvements to the codes over the last 20 years.  On the other hand, it seems to me that if the motor is turning and the door is not moving, then it has to be a mechanical drive issue like a broken shear pin, not a controller problem.

Answer (score 1):

At 20 years the controller probably has failed. But if he did not look at it I would question his diagnosis. There are things in some openers like belts that break, some direct drive couplers the coupler breaks or a sheer pin,  if the door did not make its turn off cog or sensor the motor would keep running trying to make it. The frequency band has changed over the years along with the safety eyes and even motor requirements have changed for energy efficiency so it is possible the newer model controller is not compatible but I would want to check the mechanical out. When you push the button can you hear the motor stop and reverse directions? If so I would say it is a broken drive component not the controller.